# Select-option weird behaviour on mobile device

Tags: html, css, select

If you use mobile device in inspector for example iPhone 12 pro and open the select component, the contained options are displayed above the select component, however if i change the device to iPhone XR in the chrome browser there is no problem.
I dont know what causing this issue, and how can it be fixed?
[image]

I have literally tried not to apply any css, so only pure html select and option but the issue still persists on some mobile device.

Comment: could you share a jsfiddle, or codepen example link, thanks

Comment: sure, Please check different mobile devices in chrome browser:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/selectoption-example-rj7ov?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, it seems to be a browser glitch. tested on iphone 12 pro in chrome, had no issues.

Comment: try doing dev mode in this -> https://rj7ov.csb.app/

using the iphone 12 pro